# How to create a persistent data volume for Postgres Database container in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, patroni

I have several Postgresql services, and some other services which useful in my case (for creating HA Postgresql cluster). This cluster is described in docker-compose below:

```
    version: '3.3'
services:

  haproxy:
    image: haproxy:alpine
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
        - "5001:5001"
        - "8008:8008"
    configs: 
      - haproxy_cfg
    networks:
      - dbs
    command: haproxy -f /haproxy_cfg

  etcd:
    image: quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.1.2
    configs:
      - etcd_cfg
    networks: 
      - dbs
    command: /bin/sh /etcd_cfg

  dbnode1:
    image: seocahill/patroni:1.2.5
    secrets: 
      - patroni.yml
    environment:
      - PATRONI_NAME=dbnode1
      - PATRONI_POSTGRESQL_DATA_DIR=data/dbnode1
      - PATRONI_POSTGRESQL_CONNECT_ADDRESS=dbnode1:5432
      - PATRONI_RESTAPI_CONNECT_ADDRESS=dbnode1:8008
    env_file:
      - test.env
    networks:
      - dbs
    entrypoint: patroni
    command: /run/secrets/patroni.yml

  dbnode2:
    image: seocahill/patroni:1.2.5
    secrets: 
      - patroni.yml
    environment:
      - PATRONI_NAME=dbnode2
      - PATRONI_POSTGRESQL_DATA_DIR=data/dbnode2
      - PATRONI_POSTGRESQL_CONNECT_ADDRESS=dbnode2:5432
      - PATRONI_RESTAPI_CONNECT_ADDRESS=dbnode2:8008
    env_file:
      - test.env
    networks:
      - dbs
    entrypoint: patroni
    command: /run/secrets/patroni.yml

  dbnode3:
    image: seocahill/patroni:1.2.5
    secrets: 
      - patroni.yml
    environment:
      - PATRONI_NAME=dbnode3
      - PATRONI_POSTGRESQL_DATA_DIR=data/dbnode3
      - PATRONI_POSTGRESQL_CONNECT_ADDRESS=dbnode3:5432
      - PATRONI_RESTAPI_CONNECT_ADDRESS=dbnode3:8008
    env_file:
      - test.env
    networks:
      - dbs
    entrypoint: patroni
    command: /run/secrets/patroni.yml

networks:
  dbs:
    external: true

configs:
  haproxy_cfg:
    file: config/haproxy.cfg
  etcd_cfg:
    file: config/etcd.sh

secrets:
  patroni.yml:
    file: patroni.test.yml
```

I took this yml-code from `https://github.com/seocahill/ha-postgres-docker-stack.git`. And i use next command to deploy this services in docker swarm - `docker network create -d overlay --attachable dbs && docker stack deploy -c docker-stack.test.yml test_pg_cluster`. But if i create some databases and insert some data to it and then restart servies - my data will be lost. 
I know that i need to use `volume` for saving data on host.
I create volume with docker command: `docker volume create pgdata` with default docker volume directory and mount it like this:

```
dbnode1:
        image: seocahill/patroni:1.2.5
        secrets: 
          - patroni.yml
        environment:
          - PATRONI_NAME=dbnode1
          - PATRONI_POSTGRESQL_DATA_DIR=data/dbnode1
          - PATRONI_POSTGRESQL_CONNECT_ADDRESS=dbnode1:5432
          - PATRONI_RESTAPI_CONNECT_ADDRESS=dbnode1:8008
        env_file:
          - test.env
        volumes:
          pgdata:/data/dbnode1
        networks:
          - dbs
        entrypoint: patroni
        command: /run/secrets/patroni.yml

        volumes:
           pgdata:
```

When container started it has own configs in data directory **data/dbnode1** inside container. And if i mount volume `pgdata` for store data in host, i can't connect to db and there is empty folder in container directory **data/dbnode1**. How can i create a persistent data volume for saving changed data in PostgerSQL?

Comment: e.g. docker swarm will not sync volumes between cluster nodes, a bind mount from a host is not suggested unless you add a placement constraint for the service as if the service crashes and is rescheduled onto a different node then you’ll “loose” your data - you should create the docker volumes in a nfs share that can be accessed from all nodes. Can have a look at [this compose file](https://github.com/masseybradley/playground/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is way easier to create `volumes` by adding the path directly. Check this example.

```
dbnode1:
        image: seocahill/patroni:1.2.5
        secrets: 
          - patroni.yml
        environment:
          - PATRONI_NAME=dbnode1
          - PATRONI_POSTGRESQL_DATA_DIR=data/dbnode1
          - PATRONI_POSTGRESQL_CONNECT_ADDRESS=dbnode1:5432
          - PATRONI_RESTAPI_CONNECT_ADDRESS=dbnode1:8008
        env_file:
          - test.env
        volumes:
          - /opt/dbnode1/:/data/dbnode1
        networks:
          - dbs
        entrypoint: patroni
        command: /run/secrets/patroni.yml
```

Note the lines

```
        volumes:
          - /opt/dbnode1/:/data/dbnode1
```

where I am using a the path `/opt/dbnode1/` to store the filesystem from the container at `/data/dbnode1`.

Also it is important to note that docker swarm **does not create folders** for you. Thus, you have to create the folder before starting the service. Run `mkdir -p /opt/dbnode1` to do so.

Comment: you proposed to use bind mounts instead of docker managed volumes. 
note the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)
`The file or directory does not need to exist on the Docker host already. It is created on demand if it does not yet exist`

Comment: That is why I am pointing the creation of the folder in the host.

Comment: no, no need to create the folder in the host. That's what written in the docs. You can try it and see that it's auto created

Comment: You don't know what host it is referring to. The docs state `DOCKER HOST` will be autocreated `BUT` the actual machine where you run the container will not autocreate the folder. You will get the following error: `invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: $PATH_IN_MACHINE`